# Java 8 - add property of object to list

Tags: list, java-8

I have an empty list of integers:

```
final List<Integer> reservedMarkers = new ArrayList<>();
```

and I will fill this list with the marker property of a list of objects, such like this:

```
scheduleIntervalContainers.stream().forEach(s -> s.getMarker(), reservedMarkers.add(s));
```

My final target would be to get the highest marker number but actually I dont know a better way as getting all marker numbers, than sort it and than get the highest one.

this does not work for sure, is there a possibility to do this in this way?

Comment: **There are other methods than `forEach`**. And there is a [documented API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/?java/util/stream/Stream.html). Look there first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `IntStream` to find max value:

```
OptionalInt max = scheduleIntervalContainers.stream()
    .mapToInt(s -> s.getMarker())
    .max();
```